# React modal shifting elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu in React but I'm having trouble with the modal shifting/moving elements when it opens. The dropdown menu looks similar to the spotify dropdown button which allows you to add to playlists or add to queue. The issue is that whenever the modal opens, the elements around the modal shift around to make space. I tried messing around with position absolute but with absolute the dropdown menu only appears in one area. I think position relative is the correct choice here but still having issues with other the elements shifting

```
    var data = content.map((item) => {
    return <li key ={Object.keys(item)} className={styles.item}>
                <div className={styles.content_container}>
                    {Object.values(item)}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div className = {styles.circle_container} onClick = {() => handleOptions(Object.keys(item))}>
                <div className = {styles.circle}></div><div className = {styles.circle}></div><div className = {styles.circle}></div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div className = {styles.name_item}>{Object.keys(item)}</div>
                <nav ref = {dropdownRef} className = {modal[0] === Object.keys(item)[0] ? styles.active : styles.inactive}>
                    <ul className = {styles.dropdown_menu}>
                        <li className = {styles.dropdown_item}>Create Playlist</li>
                        <li className = {styles.dropdown_item}>Add to Playlist</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </li>
})

.circle_container{
width: 20px;
height: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
position: relative;
}
.circle{
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.active{
    background: #181B2C;
    position:fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 160px;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 200px;

}
.inactive{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown_menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown_item{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 12px;
 
}
```

Comment: The modal should be absolutely positioned to its parent element. The parent element should have a relative position.

Comment: Thanks @ultra_rn